# Scraped Python results have changed from numbers to NaN

Tags: python, web-scraping

the last time I ran this code in February, it gave me proper results like this.

```
 Sales     Income
```

AAPL   365.82B     94.68B

MSFT   184.90B     71.19B

TSLA    53.82B      5.52B

FB     112.33B     40.30B

Now I get this with NaN instead of the numbers. The Finviz website looks to be using the exact same table as back in February. Can anyone figure out what has changed?  Thanks.

```
 Sales     Income
```

AAPL   365.82B     94.68B

MSFT   NaN          NaN

TSLA   NaN          NaN

FB     NaN          NaN

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import numpy as np

# For custom list of stocks, edit this list below, otherwise leave commented out
v1 = ['AAPL','MSFT','TSLA','FB','BRK-B','TSM','NVDA','V','JNJ','JPM','WMT','PG','BAC','HD','BABA','TM','XOM','PFE','DIS','KO']
# Header required to scrape from Finviz
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
           'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'Cookie': 'v2=1495343816.182.19.234.142', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
           'Referer': "http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="}
    
# This function is what is used to find the metric of interest and return it
def fundamental_metric(soup, metric):
    return soup.find(text=metric).find_next(class_='snapshot-td2').text
    
# This function iterates through the index of the data frame (stock_list) and uses the fundemental_metric functinon to find the metric on Finviz for that stock
# Any stock in the list that cannot be scraped will return an error before moving on to the next stock
def get_fundamental_data(df):
    for symbol in df.index:
        try:
            #url = ("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + symbol.lower())
            r = requests.get("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="+ symbol.lower(),headers=headers)
            soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser')
            for m in df.columns:
                output = fundamental_metric(soup,m)
                df.loc[symbol,m] = output
                df.replace(['-'], np.NaN)
        except Exception as e:
            print (symbol, 'Not Found')
            print(e)
        return df
    
# List of metrics to scrape
# Before adding any metrics, ensure the metric being added is available on Finviz and the name is matched identically
metric = ['Sales','Income']
    
df = pd.DataFrame(index = v1, columns = metric)
df = get_fundamental_data(df)
    
print(df)
```

Comment: Did you inspect on screen and see data in the table against Market Cap? I don't know if it is timings but I am seeing the cap outside of a table and inside a b tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was running for the first symbol only

```py
def get_fundamental_data(df):
    for symbol in df.index:
        try:
            # url = ("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + symbol.lower())
            r = requests.get("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + symbol.lower(), headers=headers)
            soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
            for m in df.columns:
                output = fundamental_metric(soup, m)
                df.loc[symbol, m] = output
                df.replace(['-'], np.NaN)
        except Exception as e:
            print(symbol, 'Not Found')
            print(e)
    return df #removed One tab space
```